# Find maximum number in discrete groups in spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of numbers, each group of numbers is separated from the other group by the number zero "0" or many zeros. I would like excel to get the maximum number of each group and post it in a cell automatically.

Comment: Do you have these numbers in one column or all over the spreadsheet?

Comment: You could most probably use a pivot table, in which case this question belongs on SuperUser.com.

Comment: are the zeroes one per cell vertically, or horizontally, or are the many zeroes all in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to agree with the Pivot Table approach as a quick win. Either that or a small amount VBA that itterates through your list defining the active block of numbers and then finding the max in that section.

It shouldn't be too hard to code. Perhaps post some sample data?